# How to properly define the maximum thread number in mkl on mac computers

Tags: multithreading, blas, intel-mkl

The behaviour of mkl_set_num_threads(n) and mkl_get_max_threads() seems to be different on mac and linux. Here is a small code snippet to show the different behaviours and the output from mac and linux.

It seems that on mac the mkl_get_max_threads() return the number of physical cores on my machine unless the mkl_set_num_threads_local(n) function has been set. Where on Linux it returns the mkl_set_num_threads(n) if that one has been set.

Am I missing any settings that can affect the threading to not fall back on the global settings.

```
#include "mkl.h"
#include "iostream"

int main()
{
    mkl_verbose(1);
    MKLVersion Version;
    mkl_get_version(&Version);

    printf("Major version:           %d\n",Version.MajorVersion);
    printf("Minor version:           %d\n",Version.MinorVersion);
    printf("Update version:          %d\n",Version.UpdateVersion);
    printf("Product status:          %s\n",Version.ProductStatus);
    printf("Build:                   %s\n",Version.Build);
    printf("Platform:                %s\n",Version.Platform);
    printf("Processor optimization:  %s\n",Version.Processor);
    printf("================================================================\n");
    printf("\n");

    // Here just to show these environment variables are not set.
    if(const char* env_p = std::getenv("MKL_NUM_THREADS"))
        std::cout << "Your MKL_NUM_THREADS is: " << env_p << '\n';
    if(const char* env_p = std::getenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS"))
        std::cout << "Your OMP_NUM_THREADS is: " << env_p << '\n';
    if(const char* env_p = std::getenv("NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"))
        std::cout << "Your NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS is: " << env_p << '\n';
    if(const char* env_p = std::getenv("VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"))
        std::cout << "Your VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS is: " << env_p << '\n';
    if(const char* env_p = std::getenv("OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"))
        std::cout << "Your OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS is: " << env_p << '\n';

    std::cout << mkl_get_dynamic() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mkl_get_max_threads() << std::endl;
    mkl_set_num_threads(4);
    std::cout << mkl_get_dynamic() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mkl_get_max_threads() << std::endl;
    mkl_set_num_threads_local(0);
    std::cout << mkl_get_dynamic() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mkl_get_max_threads() << std::endl;
    mkl_set_num_threads_local(4);
    std::cout << mkl_get_dynamic() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mkl_get_max_threads() << std::endl;
    mkl_set_num_threads_local(0);
    std::cout << mkl_get_dynamic() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mkl_get_max_threads() << std::endl;
}
```

Output from a mac on GCC or Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)

```
Output from a macMajor version:           2023
Minor version:           0
Update version:          1
Product status:          Product
Build:                   20230303
Platform:                Intel(R) 64 architecture
Processor optimization:  Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (Intel(R) AVX2) enabled processors
================================================================

1
8
1
8
1
8
1
4
1
8
```

Output from a linux gcc/icc/icx compilers

```
Major version:           2022
Minor version:           0
Update version:          2
Product status:          Product
Build:                   20220804
Platform:                Intel(R) 64 architecture
Processor optimization:  Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions 512 (Intel(R) AVX-512) with support of Intel(R) Deep Learning Boost (Intel(R) DL Boost), EVEX-encoded AES and Carry-Less Multiplication Quadword instructions
================================================================
1
1
1
4
1
4
1
4
1
4
```

Note: I did try the 2022 version on my mac and the same issue persist.

Comment: To set the maximum number of threads, use the mkl_set_num_threads function, To retrieve the maximum number of threads that Intel MKL can utilize, you can use the mkl_get_max_threads function. It returns the maximum number of threads that were set using mkl_set_num_threads. 

The mkl_get_max_threads function returns the maximum number of threads that can be utilized by Intel MKL on your system based on your system configuration. Setting the MKL_NUM_THREADS environment variable allows you to control how many threads are utilized by Intel MKL when running multi-threaded applications.

Comment: @Shanmukh-Intel Thank you for you response. But as you can see in the code snippet above setting `mkl_set_num_threads(4);` on a mac platform does not change the output of `mkl_get_max_threads()`.  Only when setting `mkl_set_num_threads_local(4);` does it affect  `mkl_get_max_threads()` which is an issue since the behaviour is different then expected. The number of threads used by mkl seems to be correct.